# WebView doesn't fire Navigation events in YouTube

Tags: javascript, c#, youtube, win-universal-app

I have an app where I rely quite heavily on Navigation events from [WebView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.webview.aspx) (e.g. DOMContentLoaded or NavigationCompleted). Problem is, YouTube (and, I imaging, some other websites as well) do not fire those events when you go from one video to another. I'm not a web expert, but I imaging this is because YouTube does all navigation inside of a frame. And indeed, FrameNavigationCompleted does fire for YouTube video navigation.

Usually I don't care much about frame events because a lot of useless stuff going on there. But now, I guess, I have to determine somehow that I need to listen frame instead of WebView itself. Otherwise, I can't determine if Url of the current page has changed or not, and two-way binding to WebView's Source property doesn't work for some reason.

Btw, that [JavaScript Browser](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/JSBrowser) Microsoft made suffers from the same problem because of the same reason.

Is there any good way to differentiate those two cases? Any javascript I can run which will tell me if the site does all its work inside of a frame, or some other technique?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up checking WebView.Source property in each frame navigation event and comparing it to current URL, assuming that if they are different, navigation has occurred.

I guess this would be a bit easier with working two-way binding to WebView.Source, but this is not the case for me.